# extracting a substring with regex in perl

Tags: regex, linux, perl

Okay, I have a problem that is driving me nuts. I'm trying to extract a substring with regex using:

```
($var) = $data =~ m/regex/;
```

It's working, but the "string" that's returned isn't quite the same as the real substr. Printing the string looks like the real substr, but checking with an if ($var eq "substr") doesn't return true. I've also noticed that when I try to add something to the end of it with $var .= ".."; I get (if $var is "hello") "..llo".

What is this returning?

I'm running this in Linux if that makes a difference. I wouldn't think it would, but this same code works in Windows for me.

Here's an example of the code:

```
$datatxt contains
.. 
udir=/home/me/ 
..

use File::Read;
my $data = read_file( {skip_comments => 1}, $datatxt);

($udir) = $data =~ m/udir=(.*)/;
print $udir; #prints /home/me/
print ".".$udir."."; #prints ..home/me/
if ($udir ne "/home/me/") {
   print "not equal"; #prints...
}
```

Comment: Do you have any groups in your regex?

Comment: You have a `\r` in the mix somewhere that is causing it. ( do `print "hello\r..\n";` and see the result). Windows and \*nix use different EOL - specifically, \*nix doesn't use `\r`. If you post *an actual example* we might be able to offer additional insight.

Comment: ohh that makes a lot of sense. I copied the data file that's being read from my windows partition. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The string ends with a carriage return.

```
print "hello\r..\n";   # Looks like "..llo"
```

Useful in these situations:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Dumper($str));
```

Probably the best solution is change

```
chomp;
```

to

```
s/\s+\z//;
```

It trims all trailing whitespace instead of just the trailing line feed.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide specific code. I tried with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$_ = <>;
if (($a) = $_ =~ m/(hello)/) {
    print "it is equal\n" if ($a eq "hello");
    $a .= "..";
    print "$a\n";
} else { 
    print "unmatched\n";
}
```

which should reproduce your problem, and the match works. I'm running linux, with perl v5.14.2. On input "hello world", the output is:

```
it is equal
hello..
```